# Why did my Python code get the IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I ran the code, I encountered the following error :

> IndexError: list index out of range

What is wrong in my code?

```py
fin = open('words.txt')

for line in fin:
    word = line.strip()
    if len(word) > 20:
        print(word)

print(fin.readlines()[1])  #It is in this line that the error report shows
```

Comment: Use a context manager to handle files. That `readlines()` will produce nothing since you’re at the end of the file. Please see: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Can you explain what you’re trying to do with this code?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get second element (starting from zero) of the result of execution `readlines` method. It's unsafe by default as file can contain only one string.
But in this particular case you will receive empty list in `fin.readlines()` regardless to count of lines in opened file because you've already read lines above (using `for line in fin` loop). You can't just read it twice and need to seek to the beginning or reopen file:

```
~  echo 1 >> t.txt
~  echo 2 >> t.txt
~  echo 3 >> t.txt
~  python3
```

Twice reading contents:

```
>>> with open('t.txt') as f:
...   f.readlines()
...   f.readlines()
...
['1\n', '2\n', '3\n']
[]
```

Seeking to begin:

```
>>> with open('t.txt') as f:
...   f.readlines()
...   f.seek(0)
...   f.readlines()
...
['1\n', '2\n', '3\n']
0
['1\n', '2\n', '3\n']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because file read after the loop has already reached its end.
With `seek`, you can set the pointer again to the beginning.

```
fin = open('text_file.txt')

for line in fin:
    word = line.strip()
    if len(word) > 20:
        print(word)
fin.seek(0, 0)
print(fin.readlines()[1])
```

Here is a link to it https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/file/seek.html

It is unclear what exactly you want to do still? But the error should disappear.